# MS Word does not have permission to open Word files after Ventura 13.3 update

Tags: ms-office, bug, ventura, sandbox

I've recently updated my Mac to Ventura 13.3. Since then, I'm experiencing major problem with opening Word files from Finder.

Some files can be opened without a problem, some just can't. To be honest, I'm absolutely sick of it, because Word is my daily driver that I use for my work.

Clicking on the file just opens Word, but not the file. The file can be opened though directly through Word (File>Open>...). But when I edit it and try to save it, Word asks to grant permission for the file. When I grant it, it just doesn't work anyway. I'm forced to "create new file" by using the "save as" feature.

I've already tried reinstalling the Office suite (Office 2019 btw.), but it's of no use. It's clearly caused by the macOS update.

I've also spent many hours searching the web and trying variuos fixes, but nothing helps. Is anyone else experiencing this kind of difficulty? Any ideas how to fix this? Or do I have to just hope that the next Word/macOS update will fix this?

Comment: I have macOS 13.3 but MS Word 16.72 as part of my Microsoft 365 subscription. I am not experiencing any issue as you have described with Word. Might be an issue specific to the Office 2019 version. Are you having the same problem with Excel and Powerpoint from Office 2019 or just Word?

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by a system-wide bug, that occurred in Ventura 13.3 update. Many people are experiencing this issue. It's NFC / NFD Unicode UTF-8-MAC issue. It seems it is happening on files (most probably not only) with UTF-8 encoded diacritics. Example in the Czech language: `řžýá.docx` will result in files not opening, `rzya.docx` will open fine.

For more information check these Apple discussions:

- [I cannot open files(especially PDF files) after update ventura 13.2.1 to 13.3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254748658)
- [Issue opening files from Google Drive Finder window after installing macOS Ventura 13.3 update](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254746547)

Comment: I have Word and PDF files with names having characters with diacritics but still can't replicate the problem(s) described. In any case, I suggest you at least report this via [Apple Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/). As a partial workaround to opening a file is concerned, have you tried using Command+O in the Finder instead of the double-click?

Comment: I've already sent feedback to Apple. Command + O is no use as well. Important note is that files created on macOS or OS that stores letters the same way as mac works just fine. Files created in Windows or any other os/service that uses different method of saving letters, then sent through cloud service, mail, or downloaded from web, will face this issue. It's explained in this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/12dwpqq/ventura_133_sandbox_mode_bug/